# Splitting first sentence of string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is a paragraph that I am attempting to use the `split` method to return just the first sentence of that paragraph. My goal is to append the first sentence and the rest of the paragraph separately. I'm able to return the first sentence, but I am also expecting the first sentence to no longer appear from the original `data`. In this case even though I split the first sentence successfully it does remain in `data` how can I have separate these two?

For example :

```js
 const data = "The amount spent on gasoline continues to be a large expense to many individuals. The average amount spent on gasoline per year is $2000. This number can easily change as the price of gasoline is rapidly changing."

let firstSentence = data.split('\.', 1)[0];

console.log(firstSentence)

console.log(data)
```

My expected outcome is:

`first sentence: "The amount spent on gasoline continues to be a large expense to many individuals."`

`data: "The average amount spent on gasoline per year is $2000. This number can easily change as the price of gasoline is rapidly changing.`

Comment: _"but I am also expecting the first sentence to no longer appear from the original `data`"_ - [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an array of all the substrings. Why should it modify the content of the source string? o.O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are [immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable). No method or any operation you do to the string in `data` will modify the string - functions like `.split()` just return new data, they do not mutate the original data.

`.split()` returns an array with each part. You are using the second parameter already to limit it to one split, so the rest of the sentences past the first are not returned. Instead, you could get all splits and just re-join the ones after the first.

```js
 const data = "The amount spent on gasoline continues to be a large expense to many individuals. The average amount spent on gasoline per year is $2000. This number can easily change as the price of gasoline is rapidly changing."

let sentences = data.split('\.');
let firstSentence = sentences.shift(); //remove and return first element
let rest = sentences.join('.').trim(); //undo split and trim the space

console.log(firstSentence)
console.log(rest)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the`data.split('\.')` without specifying at the end of a period? For example, there is one sentence that has a percentage in the sentence `1.1%` so it is splitting at the `1.1` instead of the `.` at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @maimok You could consider splitting on `'. '` (period then space) which ought to take care of most of those situations

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the second element of the array to `data` for `data` to contain that value. `split()` does not actually modify the array.

```js
let data = "The amount spent on gasoline continues to be a large expense to many individuals. The average amount spent on gasoline per year is $2000. This number can easily change as the price of gasoline is rapidly changing."; // Original data

const arr = data.split(/\./); // Split data

let firstSentence = arr[0]; // Set firstSentence to the first item of array

arr.shift(); // Remove first item

data = arr.join('. '); // Set data to the rest of the array

console.log(firstSentence)

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
let data = "The amount spent on gasoline continues to be a large expense to many individuals. The average amount spent on gasoline per year is $2000. This number can easily change as the price of gasoline is rapidly changing."

let firstSentence = data.split('\.', 1)[0];

data = data.replace(firstSentence + '. ', '');
console.log(firstSentence)

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

update your data object after you get the first sentence you need.

```
let data = "The amount spent on gasoline continues to be a large expense to many individuals. The average amount spent on gasoline per year is $2000. This number can easily change as the price of gasoline is rapidly changing."

let firstSentence = data.split('\.', 1)[0];

console.log(firstSentence)
data = data.split('.').splice(1).join() // just add this line
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Why `.split()` twice? With different separators?

Comment: I have not touched the code which was working. Just gave a solution for how to add all array elements but first one. Same split would be better.

Comment: `.splice()` returns the elements that were *removed*, not the rest of the array. Perhaps you meant `.slice()`?

Comment: yes we can use ```slice()``` also but I have used ```splice()``` and assigned the spliced value to data again. ```slice()``` is a better solution actually...

Comment: @Anup ah I see, my mistake, your solution works just fine too. I didn't think of doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the first **n** sentences of a string.

This is pretty straightforward.

Modify n to get a different number of sentences

```
var n = 3; // Make this the number of sentences you want to get

var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

// Substitute n in your slice below
var output = str.split(".").slice(0,n).join(".") + ".";

console.log(output);
```